# SQLAlchemy: how to filter with dictionary value?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a database table like this:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | res_id    | path                   | overrides         |
|-------------------------------------------------------------|
| 1  | res_1     | res_1                  | {"enabled": True} |
| 2  | res_1.1   | res_1.res_1.1          | {"enabled": False}|
| 3  | res_1.2   | res_1.res_1.2          | {"enabled": False}|
| 4  | res_1.1.1 | res_1.res_1.1.res_1.1.1| {"enabled": False}|
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The `overrides` is for setting a breaking point to inheritance. So, if I query the `res_1.1.1`m I'd normally get also resources 1 & 2, because of the inheritance. But now, there is `"enabled": True` in `1` and it doesn't inherit anywhere, so the query would return only 2 & 4.
 The question is, how  can I filter out objects where the `overrides` is `"enabled": True`? I've tried e.g. this: 
`.filter(MyModel.overrides["enabled"] is not True)`, this doesn't seem to work. 
 I've also tried using dictionary methods `get()`, `values()` and `keys()`, but they give me an error, e.g. `AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with MyModel.overrides has an attribute 'get'`.
 The field `overrides` in a `JSONB` -field.

Comment: @AlbertoHanna the JSON and JSONB are automatically loaded by SQLAlchemy, see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is two things here you're missing.

Firstly, `.filter(col is not True)` cannot be compiled by SQLAlchemy, I recommend you use `.filter(col == False)` or `.filter(col.is_(False))`.

Then to access the value inside the the JSONB dict, you need to cast it to a SQL type, for instance with [`.as_boolean()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.JSON.Comparator.as_boolean).

Putting both of those together, we get:

```py
stmt = (
    select(MyModel)
    .filter(MyModel.overrides["enabled"].as_boolean() == False)
)
```

---

Full script demo:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql

metadata_obj = sa.MetaData()

t = sa.Table(
    "t72632977",
    metadata_obj,
    sa.Column("id", sa.Integer, primary_key=True),
    sa.Column("res_id", sa.String),
    sa.Column("path", sa.String),
    sa.Column("overrides", postgresql.JSONB),
)

engine = sa.create_engine(
    "postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/postgres",
    echo=True,
    future=True,
)

metadata_obj.create_all(engine)

with engine.begin() as con:
    con.execute(
        sa.insert(t),
        [
            {
                "res_id": "res_1",
                "path": "res_1",
                "overrides": {"enabled": True},
            },
            {
                "res_id": "res_1.1",
                "path": "res_1.res_1.1",
                "overrides": {"enabled": False},
            },
            {
                "res_id": "res_1.2",
                "path": "res_1.res_1.2",
                "overrides": {"enabled": False},
            },
            {
                "res_id": "res_1.1.1",
                "path": "res_1.res_1.1.res_1.1.1",
                "overrides": {"enabled": False},
            },
        ],
    )

with engine.connect() as con:
    r = con.execute(
        sa.select(t).filter(t.c.overrides["enabled"].as_boolean() == False)
    )
    print(r.all())

# emits
# SELECT t72632977.id, t72632977.res_id, t72632977.path, t72632977.overrides 
# FROM t72632977 
# WHERE CAST((t72632977.overrides ->> %(overrides_1)s) AS BOOLEAN) = false

# returns
# [
#     (2, 'res_1.1', 'res_1.res_1.1', {'enabled': False}),
#     (3, 'res_1.2', 'res_1.res_1.2' , {'enabled': False}),
#     (4, 'res_1.1.1', 'res_1.res_1.1.res_1.1.1', {'enabled': False}),
# ]
```

Comment: Thank you. What about if I need to compare the `MyModel.overrides["enabled"]` to a part of a `ltree ` path? Any hints how the ltree should be treated when comparing these?

Comment: @lr_optim I won't be much help about `LTREE`, I have never used it myself.